# Failure to create "Figure" from an Image, inserted two-column inline

Tags: floats, two-column, multicol, inline

I am attempting to use "in-line" images *as LaTeX figures* (so that they can be numbered and appear in the Table of Figures), in a two-column document created with the package << multicols >>.
If I use this "normal" construction syntax:
  `

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    [
    \section{First Section}
    \large{\textsl{All human things are subject to decay. And when fate summons, Monarchs must obey.\todo{findreference}}}\normalsize
    ]
        \lipsum[1-2]
        %\begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=0.50\textwidth]{placeholder.png}        \caption{\textbf{\textit{Here is an inline image}}}
        
        %\label{fig:The placeholder logo}
        %\end{figure}
        
        \lipsum[4-6]
    ]
    \textbf{This is the end of the First Section}
    
\end{multicols}
` ` `
```

the image disappears from the column(NB: here the offending lines have been % away).

If this construct doesn't work,

1. Why does it fail (e.g., using the <> vs specifying
   [twocolumns] option in the document class)?
2. How do I turn these images into "Figures" ??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can test as it is. Use of the package `multicolumn` doesn't allow  floating environments. Why you use `\begin{multicols}{2}`? Does option `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}` not provide what you after?

Comment: Aside: `\large` is a switch, not a command, so `\large{Stuff}` is the same as `\large Stuff` and will make everything large until the group ends or you get to `\normalsize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multicol` does not support floats, but you can use `\captionof{figure}{<text>}` to add a caption for the inline figure (package `caption`).

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{caption} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    
        \section{First Section}
        {\large\textsl{All human things are subject to decay. And when fate summons, Monarchs must obey.\todo{findreference}}}
    
        \lipsum[1-2]
            
        \noindent\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}        
        \captionof{figure}{\textbf{\textit{Here is an inline image\label{fig:The placeholder logo}}}}   % added <<<<<<< 
        
        \lipsum[4-6]
        
        \textbf{This is the end of the First Section}
        
    \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

`todonotes` will not work but you can list them at the end of the document adding

```
\newpage
\listoftodos[Notes]
```

**Option** using `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}` to allow floats.

[[image: b2]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{caption} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{todonotes}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.5cm} % added to have todonote  in the margin<<<
\begin{document}
    
    \section{First Section}
    {\large\textsl{All human things are subject to decay. And when fate summons, Monarchs must obey.\todo{find reference}}}
    
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}         
        \caption{\textbf{\textit{Here is an inline image\label{fig:The placeholder logo}}}} 
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[4-6]
    
    \textbf{This is the end of the First Section}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful insights on [twocolumns] vs [multicols]. Indeed, I am going to continue to use [multicols] because it allows me to use full-width headers for Sections / subsections (etc) and flexibility with in-column or column-spanning images.
I am very grateful for the pointer to the package {caption} and the command \captionof , the use of which does generate entries in the Table of Figures!

Package **{hyperref} "doesn't play nicely"** with package {todo} in the {multicols} environment. If a work-around exists, or you have hacking suggestions, by all means let me know!

Answer (score -1):

This problem seems to have resulted from a call to the `hyperref` package.

The call to `hyperref` also caused problems with implementing the `xcolor` package. Please see my answer to [that question about Dvips / Dvipsnames](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670350/dvips-sty-missing-from-recent-texlive-distro).